# Does Windows cache the contents of .url (Internet Shortcut) files?

Tags: windows, url, shortcut

I'm implementing a custom URL handler in .NET. To test this, I have created a few different `.url` files and put them on my Desktop. This generally works fine, but behaves oddly if I change the file's contents, specifically the `URL=` line. Doing so has no effect — the old URL continues to be opened. Renaming the file, however, works. The file looks like this:

```
[{000214A0-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}]
Prop3=19,0
[InternetShortcut]
URL=myCustomScheme://some/url/pointing/somewhere
IDList=
```

All shortcuts I create through *New → Shortcut* receive the same UUID, so changing that probably won't help.

Is there some internal .url file / URL mapping cache in Windows?

Comment: I just tested this with http URLs on Windows XP and it picked up the changes.  Are you sure your handler is working properly?

Comment: I can reproduce this with `http:` URLs, too. Windows 7, x64.

Comment: Hmm, there does seem to be some kind of caching on Windows 7.  Funny thing is that it doesn't happen every time; sometimes it goes to the new URL and sometimes the old URL.  It seems like if you close Internet Explorer and then launch the shortcut it goes to the right location.

Comment: I have a similar issue in Win XP... the changes in the file are not taken into account until I restart explorer.exe

Comment: Did you ever find anything out about this, we are having some issues with this as well (on win7)

Comment: I'm also running into this problem. Interestingly enough I deleted the entire contents of the .url file and it still worked. If I renamed the file then it picked up the changes but if I switched the name BACK the link (with no contents in the file) worked again!

Comment: Clearing Temporary Internet Files might help, and any additional cache that's used by Internet Explorer.

Comment: The UUID you are talking about is always the same because it is the COM UUID of the internet shortcut format. The Prop3 entry is undocumented but it is often 19,2 in a valid file.

Answer (score 2):

I have a reason to believe that URL files are interpreted by some Internet Explorer component at the time of creation <s>(not biblical)</s>. They are only interpreted initially, the first time the file is created. Any modifications to the URL file later on will not be committed. This is because the shortcut is not stored in the file. This is why the file can be modified later on so that it becomes empty, as a 0 byte file and the URL file will appear to be working anyway. The shortcut data is stored in the "Web Document" field as a file property in the NTFS file system. The file merely serves the purpose of pointing to it. You might be able to modify these property fields programmatically, which would supposedly "edit the file". It's a painful exercise just to edit what appears to be a simple text file.

Additionally, once a file name has been used for a URL file, it cannot be reused for new files, no matter what disk or path you save it to. So you have to keep assigning unique file names, never used previously, for each new URL file you create. This has to do with how Internet Explorer caches web content. It remembers what file names have been used already and maps those names to previously defined URL addresses. To reuse a name <s>(or when you run out of ideas for new and unique file names)</s> you have to clear Temporary Internet Files.

```
Windows 7: %localappdata%\Microsoft\Windows\Temporary Internet Files
Windows 8: %localappdata%\Microsoft\Windows\INetCache
```

To directly answer your question: yes, it does.

Answer (score 1):

Windows 7 Caches your Filenames and sometimes, as you said, the filenames in specific locations.

Start regedit and search for the following

```
HKEY_USERS\S-1-5-21-x-x-x-x\Software\Classes\Local Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\MuiCache
```

where S-1-5-21-x-x-x-x is your currently logged in User.

There you can see that most (or all?) files have been cached which you have ever accessed.

Maybe you can also deactivate the MUICaching programatically. Maybe this site helps you: [Disable Caching](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724854%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: These entries only cache file properties (mostly executable file properties)

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue, and it turns out the culprit was Firefox.

If by chance your web browser is Firefox, your cache directories may be corrupted.

You can either create a new Profile, or take your chances cleaning things out of `C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\<profile>\`

Comment: This is irrelevant, unless you mean the shortcut icons which are loaded from cached site icons (cached favicons).

Answer (score 0):

I've found my desktop `.url` shortcut contents cached in `%LocalAppData%\Microsoft\Windows\Caches`.

There are a few (several?) files with filenames like `{<SOME_GUID>}.<x>.ver0x<XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX>.db`. Two of them had the `.url` files cached.

Unfortunately, I've found no information on what they are or how to refresh them. Everybody just deletes them as part of some cache clean-up operation.