# Windows Internet Shortcuts and unicode characters in URL

Tags: windows, shortcut

I have a process that creates Windows internet shortcut files (.url). The files are encoded in UTF-8. The files contain an [InternetShortcut] section, where a URL= is specified. In this case, these are file:/// protocol URLs, which allow people to open paths on their LAN. The URLs are all UNC paths.

Normally the process works fine. But when a UNC path contains Unicode characters, such as the "í" from the code sample below, Windows is unable to "find" the URL when an end user tries to open the internet shortcut from Windows Explorer:

A sample file follows:

```
[InternetShortcut]
URL=file:///\\lt-splourde\d$\POC\Montería Test\
IconIndex=1
```

When I open the sample .url file above with a text editor, I see the path with the proper Unicode characters. But when I try to open the file from Windows Explorer, in order to access the path, Windows reports that it is unable to access the path, and it seems to mangle the Unicode characters.

The source code that creates these shortcuts follows:

```
private void CreateShortcutAsUrl(string uncRootPath, string name, string path, int projectId)
{
    path = path + (path.EndsWith(@"\") ? "" : @"\");

    using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(
        String.Format(@"{0}\{1}\{2}.url", uncRootPath,
            ShortcutsDirectory, new FileServerController().SanitizeNameForDirectory(name)),
            false, Encoding.UTF8)) 
    {
        writer.WriteLine(@"[InternetShortcut]");
        writer.WriteLine(@"URL=file:///" + path);
        writer.Flush();
    }
}
```

Does anyone know of a solution for this issue?

Thanks!

(I had posted this on superuser originally, but I feel like the content is more programmer oriented)

Comment: It would be better if the process that writes the URLs uses [`InternetCanonicalizeUrl`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384342(v=vs.85).aspx) first. Is this your process? Do you have the source code?

Comment: Hi Roger, I have the source. I'll post above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the .NET equivalent of [`InternetCanonicalizeUrl`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384342%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), which is [`System.Uri.EscapeUriString`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.escapeuristring.aspx), so something like this (assuming your URI is in `szOriginalString`

```
String szEscapedString = System.Uri.EscapeUriString(szOriginalString);
```

Then write `szEscapedString` as the URI instead of the original.

Comment: Hi Roger, thanks for the suggestion. I tried revising the line as follows, but the same issue is still happening. Do you think this implementation seems correct? writer.WriteLine(@"URL=" + System.Uri.EscapeUriString("file:///" + path));

Comment: @ShanPlourde yes that looks right, it should give you `URL=file:///%5C%5Clt-splourde%5Cd$%5CPOC%5CMonter%C3%ADa%20Test%5C` but as you say, this translates differently when it tries to access it. I will think again :-(

Comment: @ShanPlourde actually just tested again and writing with `Encoding.UnicodeEncoding` *does* seem to work. Can you try? So, just change the encoding and forget about the `EscapeUriString` bit.

Comment: Well what do you know, it worked! I had tried Encoding.UnicodeEncoding yesterday evening, but then realized that IE's URL caching was getting in the way - see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3329139/does-windows-cache-the-contents-of-url-internet-shortcut-files. As a workaround, I moved the shortcut to a different subdirectory, which seems to cause Windows to not look up the shortcut from cache.