# Cache creating internet shortcuts on windows

Tags: java, windows, url, shortcut

First of all, i found some answers about my problem but did not help.
Here's one: [Does Windows cache the contents of .url (Internet Shortcut) files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3329139/does-windows-cache-the-contents-of-url-internet-shortcut-files)

I have an application that remove the actual shortcuts and create new ones:

```
for (String shortcut : shortcuts) {
    File f = new File(shortcut + ".url");
    if (f.exists()) {
        f.delete();
    }

    try {
        FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(shortcut + ".url");
        fw.write("[InternetShortcut]\n");
        fw.write("URL=http://localhost:" + port + "/" + shortcut + "\n");

        fw.flush();
        fw.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
    }
}
```

This is the result:

```
[InternetShortcut]
URL=http://localhost:8889/app
```

And it's fine, but when i change the port and create another shortcut, windows keeps opening the old url.
In the file properties i can see the right url in the details tab, but in the document of web tab still showing the old url.

As default i'm using Chrome, when i drag the .url file to the browser it work and load the right url, but if i double click loads the old url.

Thanks.

Comment: Try to disable Chrome cache `right click -> inspect element -> network -> disable cache` to see if your issue come from Chrome (I 'm not sure if disable cache works for local file).

Comment: It did not work @Duffydake ...i think it doesnt affect local files... =/