# SHChangeNotify not updating URL= change in my .url shortcut file

Tags: windows, delphi, shortcut

I have a simple Delphi application that creates a desktop shortcut for a URL. It makes a two-line text file with a `.url` filename extension in the user's Desktop folder:

```ini
[InternetShortcut]
URL=http://127.0.0.1/admin
```

That works fine. When I need to update the file with a new URL, I overwrite the old file. But Windows will not recognize the change until I restart Explorer or reboot. So I learned about `SHChangeNotify()` and called it after overwriting the file:

```delphi
SHChangeNotify(SHCNE_UPDATEITEM, SHCNF_PATH or SHCNF_FLUSH, PChar(Path), nil);
```

But it has no effect:

- I tried with and without the `SHCNF_FLUSH` flag;
- also the `SHCNF_FLUSHNOWAIT` flag makes no difference.
- I also tried deleting the file first and then using the `SHCNE_DELETE` event and then re-creating the file. That doesn't work either, it just keeps using the old URL.

How do I force Explorer to reload the URL from the file without a restart?

Comment: I forgot to mention, I've only tried this on Windows 7 so far.

Comment: Are you talking about the tooltip not updating or launching the file opens a browser to the wrong URL?

Comment: @Anders, The shortcut opens the original URL and ignores the one that is present in the .url file. Right-clicking it and checking properties also shows the old URL. It has cached it someplace and will not update until I reboot (or manually close and restart explorer.exe).

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/3329139/3501 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While the file's content can be treated like any INI file I yet have not found a direct way to control manipulations to it:

- When creating a file its content is read as expected: the system's default application for the `URL=`'s protocol is started (i.e. for `http` it is most likely the internet browser).
- Modifying the file per file systems has no effect - either MSIE itself maintains a cache or the COM's magic.

Indirectly manipulation is possible in the following way:

1. Empty the file's existing content. Why? Because the later step will just add the same INI section with an `URL=` value again, but the first section's `URL=` value remains the one that is taken into account.
2. Access the file per COM and change its properties. Sadly this writes more into the file - in my case the outcome/file's content was:

   > ```ini
   > [{000214A0-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}]
   > Prop3=19,2
   > [InternetShortcut]
   > URL=http://127.0.0.1/index.php
   > IDList=
   > ```

However, it "works" as in: the change (speak: a different URL) is recognized. Putting it all together my following code for Delphi 7 on Windows 7 should also work for you - just call the function:

```delphi
uses
  ShlObj, ActiveX, ComObj;

const
  SID_IUniformResourceLocatorA= '{FBF23B80-E3F0-101B-8488-00AA003E56F8}';
  SID_IUniformResourceLocatorW= '{CABB0DA0-DA57-11CF-9974-0020AFD79762}';
  SID_InternetShortcut= '{FBF23B40-E3F0-101B-8488-00AA003E56F8}';

type
  PUrlInvokeCommandInfoA= ^TUrlInvokeCommandInfoA;
  TUrlInvokeCommandInfoA= record
    dwcbSize,
    dwFlags: DWORD;  // Bit field of IURL_INVOKECOMMAND_FLAGS
    hwndParent: HWND;  // Parent window. Valid only if IURL_INVOKECOMMAND_FL_ALLOW_UI is set.
    pcszVerb: LPCSTR;  // Verb to invoke. Ignored if IURL_INVOKECOMMAND_FL_USE_DEFAULT_VERB is set.
  end;

  PUrlInvokeCommandInfoW= ^TUrlInvokeCommandInfoW;
  TUrlInvokeCommandInfoW= record
    dwcbSize,
    dwFlags: DWORD;
    hwndParent: HWND;
    pcszVerb: LPCWSTR;
  end;

  IUniformResourceLocatorA= interface( IUnknown )
    [SID_IUniformResourceLocatorA]
    function SetURL( pcszURL: LPCSTR; dwInFlags: DWORD ): HRESULT; stdcall;
    function GetURL( ppszURL: LPSTR ): HRESULT; stdcall;
    function InvokeCommand( purlici: PUrlInvokeCommandInfoA ): HRESULT; stdcall;

  end;

  IUniformResourceLocatorW= interface( IUnknown )
    [SID_IUniformResourceLocatorW]
    function SetURL( pcszURL: LPCWSTR; dwInFlags: DWORD ): HRESULT; stdcall;
    function GetURL( ppszURL: LPWSTR ): HRESULT; stdcall;
    function InvokeCommand(purlici: PUrlInvokeCommandInfoW ): HRESULT; stdcall;
  end;

function SetURL( sFile, sUrl: Widestring ): Integer;
const
  CLSID_InternetShortCut: TGUID= SID_InternetShortcut;
var
  oUrl: IUniformResourceLocatorW;
  oFile: IPersistFile;
  hFile: THandle;
begin
  // First, the existing file's content should be emptied
  hFile:= CreateFileW( PWideChar(sFile), GENERIC_WRITE, 0, nil, OPEN_EXISTING, 0, 0 );
  if hFile= INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE then begin
    result:= 1;  // File might not exist, sharing violation, etc.
    exit;
  end;

  // Initial file pointer is at position 0
  if not SetEndOfFile( hFile ) then begin
    result:= 2;  // Missing permissions, etc.
    CloseHandle( hFile );
    exit;
  end;

  // Gracefully end accessing the file
  if not CloseHandle( hFile ) then begin
    result:= 3;  // File system crashed, etc.
    exit;
  end;

  // Using COM to access properties
  result:= 0;
  try
    oUrl:= CreateComObject( CLSID_InternetShortCut ) as IUniformResourceLocatorW;
  except
    result:= 4;  // CLSID unsupported, COM not available, etc.
  end;
  if result<> 0 then exit;

  // Opening the file again
  oFile:= oUrl as IPersistFile;
  if oFile.Load( PWideChar(sFile), STGM_READWRITE )<> S_OK then begin
    result:= 5;  // Sharing violations, access permissions, etc.
    exit;
  end;

  // Set the property as per interface - only saving the file is not enough
  if oUrl.SetURL( PWideChar(sUrl), 0 )<> S_OK then begin
    result:= 6;
    exit;
  end;

  // Storing the file's new content - setting only the property is not enough
  if oFile.Save( PWideChar(sFile), TRUE )<> S_OK then begin
    result:= 7;
    exit;
  end;

  // Success!
  result:= 0;
end;
```

As per my desktop firewall the executing process modifies the memory of `explorer.exe` upon `IPersistFile.Save()` - after that executing the URL file should reflect its new content, while any attempt before that should still act upon the old file's content.

Comment: This worked great. But instead of emptying the existing file I just deleted it (if FileExists(sFile) then DeleteFile(sFile)) before the CreateComObject and it seems to work also.

Comment: @kbriggs then why don't you accept this answer?

Comment: sorry about that. I clicked the up vote but forgot the checkmark.